# Load many-to-many relationship and map to entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I'm fairly new to Spring Boot/Hibernate development, this was my first big project.

I have an application using Spring Boot, Hibernate and Hibernate Envers to audit some entities. Hibernate Envers is set to use the ValidityAuditStrategy.
Since Hibernate Envers doesn't support yet eager loading *to-Many* relationships out of the box, I'm trying to find a way to perform a single query and retrieve all the data I need, to avoid the N+1 queries problem that, at the moment, is killing my performance: it's taking almost 2 minutes in our development environment to completely load the entity we need with the relationships required.

Since I need to retrieve an audited version, I cannot leverage on EntityGraph like I used in other part of the application (at least to my understanding).

One of the situation I need to tackle has 4 entities `Parameter`, `Formula`, `Value` and `Variable`, that are related like this (showing only the relevant parts, `Value` and `Variable` are entities and not listed here)

```
@Entity
public class Parameter {
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "formula_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
  private Formula formula;
}

@Entity
public class Formula {
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
  private Value tag;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
      name = "Formulas_Variables",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "formula_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "variable_id"))
  private Set<Variable> variables = new HashSet<>();
}
```

What I tried to do is create a custom query and mapping the result using `@NamedNativeQuery` and `@SqlResultSetMapping` but, even though Hibernate is creating the relationship between `Formula` and `Value` correctly, it's not creating the array on `variables` field. The query and the mapping I used are the following:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "Parameter.findAllByRevisionMapping", entities = {
    @EntityResult(entityClass = Parameter.class, fields = {
        @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "id"),
        @FieldResult(name = "formula", column = "formula_id")
    }),
    @EntityResult(entityClass = Formula.class, fields = {
        @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "formulaId"),
        @FieldResult(name = "tag", column = "tag_id"),
        @FieldResult(name = "variables", column = "variable_id")
    }),
    @EntityResult(entityClass = DomainValue.class, fields = {
        @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "tag_id")
    }),
    @EntityResult(entityClass = Variable.class, fields = {
        @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "variableId")
    })
})
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "Parameter.findAllByRevision", query = "SELECT om_c_p_aud.id,\n"
    + "       f_aud.id AS formulaId,\n"
    + "       dv_aud.id AS tag_id,\n"
    + "       fv_aud.formula_id AS formula_id,\n"
    + "       v_aud.id AS variable_id,\n"
    + "       v_aud.id AS variableId\n"
    + "FROM Parameters_AUD om_c_p_aud\n"
    + "         LEFT OUTER JOIN Formulas_AUD f_aud\n"
    + "                    ON f_aud.id = om_c_p_aud.formula_id AND f_aud.REV <= ?1 AND\n"
    + "                       f_aud.REVTYPE <> 2 AND (f_aud.REVEND > ?1 OR\n"
    + "                                               f_aud.REVEND IS NULL)\n"
    + "         LEFT OUTER JOIN Values_AUD dv_aud\n"
    + "                    ON dv_aud.id = f_aud.tag_id AND dv_aud.REV <= ?1 AND\n"
    + "                       dv_aud.REVTYPE <> 2 AND (dv_aud.REVEND > ?1 OR\n"
    + "                                                dv_aud.REVEND IS NULL)\n"
    + "         LEFT OUTER JOIN Formulas_Variables_AUD fv_aud\n"
    + "                    ON fv_aud.formula_id = f_aud.id AND fv_aud.REV <= ?1 AND\n"
    + "                       fv_aud.REVTYPE <> 2 AND (fv_aud.REVEND > ?1 OR\n"
    + "                                                fv_aud.REVEND IS NULL)\n"
    + "         LEFT OUTER JOIN Variables_AUD v_aud\n"
    + "                    ON v_aud.id = fv_aud.variable_id AND v_aud.REV <= ?1 AND\n"
    + "                       v_aud.REVTYPE <> 2 AND (v_aud.REVEND > ?1 OR\n"
    + "                                               v_aud.REVEND IS NULL)\n"
    + "WHERE om_c_p_aud.REV <= ?1\n"
    + "  AND om_c_p_aud.REVTYPE <> 2\n"
    + "  AND (om_c_p_aud.REVEND > ?1 OR\n"
    + "       om_c_p_aud.REVEND IS NULL)", resultSetMapping = "Parameter.findAllByRevisionMapping")
```

An example of result from the query performed directly on the database is the following:
[image: Query example result]

The resulting array of json objects I'm receiving when calling `findAllByRevision` query is something like this

```json
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "formula":{
         "id":52,
         "tag":{
            "id":20
         },
         "variables":null
      }
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "formula":{
         "id":88,
         "tag":{
            "id":24
         },
         "variables":null
      }
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "formula":{
         "id":88,
         "tag":{
            "id":24
         },
         "variables":null
      }
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "formula":{
         "id":88,
         "tag":{
            "id":24
         },
         "variables":null
      }
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "formula":{
         "id":88,
         "tag":{
            "id":24
         },
         "variables":null
      }
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "formula":{
         "id":88,
         "tag":{
            "id":24
         },
         "variables":null
      }
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "formula":{
         "id":88,
         "tag":{
            "id":24
         },
         "variables":null
      }
   }
]
```

whereas the one I'd expect was

```json
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "formula":{
         "id":52,
         "tag":{
            "id":20
         },
         "variables":[
            {
               "id":4
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "formula":{
         "id":88,
         "tag":{
            "id":24
         },
         "variables":[
            {
               "id":3
            },
            {
               "id":23
            },
            {
               "id":33
            },
            {
               "id":34
            },
            {
               "id":35
            },
            {
               "id":52
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Does anyone have any idea why it isn't creating the formulas <-> variables relationship? I tried to check the query created by Hibernate when using an EntityGraph for a similar situation and it seemed to me the same as the one showed above. I have no way to check the mapping used in that case though (to my understanding again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use HQL to specify join fetches for the audited associations. An audited entity is just like a normal entity. The entity name is usually suffixed with "_AUD" so if you want to query the audit info of `Parameters` you could query `Parameters_AUD` like e.g.:

```
SELECT p
FROM Parameters_AUD p
LEFT JOIN FETCH p.values
LEFT JOIN FETCH p.variables
```

Comment: That would be great, but at the moment I don't have audited class entities and I get an error if I just try to add the query as is. Should I create entities for all audited classes?

Comment: To add to that, if I define  a `Parameter_AUD` I get the following error on application start ` Duplicate entity mapping com.myPackage.entities.Parameter_AUD`

Comment: You don't have to define classes for that. When you activate Hibernate Envers for such an entity, a MAP mode entity is created automatically behind the scenes. The entity name has the `_AUD` suffix so you can use that name for queries. Remove the custom defined classes. What error do you get?

Comment: The error I was getting was that `Parameter_AUD` entity did not exist. If I created an entity with that name I was getting the duplicated entity error. So after a bit I tried to use the fqn and it worked. Even though, I still had some problems, since REV, REVEND and REVTYPE columns where not accessible like in the example query, probably because they are nested in some inner object. Since I was struggling to make it work that way, I decided to use another approch and load each entity list separately, and creating relationships by hand. I'd be still interested to know how to map entities though

Comment: You are right, the entity name is the FQN + "_AUD", sorry I wasn't clear enough about that. You can inspect the entity metamodel to understand how you can access this information. Every envers entity has a `REVTYPE` and `originalId` attribute. The `originalId` attribute is of an embeddable type and has sub-attributes `id` and `REV`. Audited associations are mapped through their simple join column attributes so you need to do an entity join to join that information if you need it.